# Accessing JWT Token during verification

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I am playing with the Spring Cloud OAuth2 implementation using the following examples:

https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/authserver

https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sso

The first is an OAuth server that generates JWT tokens upon authenticating the user. The second is a resource that is being consumed. The resource relays the authentication of the user to authserver as per the OAuth spec.

All seems to work very well, leading me to additional questions:

1. In the authserver, during authentication, how can I get access to the clientId and clientSecret?
2. Can I determine which values are used for generating the JWT token?
3. In SSO, how do I get access to the content of the token (for instance, the principal) once the user is authenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to 3): change the method signature to include:

```
@AuthenticationPrincipal  User principal
```

This way the authentication credentials will be passed to the controller method called by Spring. The other way is through the security context:

```
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext(); 
Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
```

As for 2), my guess at this point is that to influence the parameters used to compute the JWT token, one needs to implement a custom     AccessTokenConverter. If my understanding is correct the default one called     DefaultAccessTokenConverter does not allow for this. I welcome any other opinion on this.